# Outputting an Enum of a Struct returns negative number

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, enumeration

My goal is to store the input.dat file into an array of a struct and output the total number of Fords, Chevys, Hondas, and Toyotas which are enumerations. I've hit a roadblock after working on this for quite a few hours. When I debug the code in Visual studio i receive negative numbers in the output. I'm stuck and could really use an explanation as to what I'm missing.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

enum CarType
{
        Ford,
        Chevy,
        Honda,
        Toyota
};

struct CarCustomer
{
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        double price;
        CarType carType;
};

void calcCarStats(CarCustomer arrCustomers[], int count, int carCount[])
{
        for(int index = 0; index < count; index++)
        {
                carCount[arrCustomers[index].carType]++;
        }
}

void displayCarTypeCounts(int carCount[])
{
        for(int index = Ford; index <= Toyota; index++)
        {
                cout //<< translateCarTypeToText((CarType)index) << " "
                        << carCount[index] << endl;
        }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
        int count = 0;
        CarCustomer arrCustomers[100]; //Array of structs for the Struct CarCustomer
        CarCustomer carCustomer;
        int carCount[100];
        int carTypeInt;
        double carPriceSum[100];
        double carPriceAvg[100];
        ifstream fin;
        CarType carType; //CarType enum

        fin.open("input.dat");

        if(!fin)
        {
                cout << "Error opening file, check the file name" << endl;
                _getch();
                return -1;
        }

        while (!fin.eof())
        {
                fin >> arrCustomers[count].firstName;
                fin >> arrCustomers[count].lastName;
                fin >> arrCustomers[count].price;
                fin >> carTypeInt;
                arrCustomers[count].carType = (CarType)carTypeInt;  //carType entry is an enum
                count++;

                //debug
                /*
                cout << arrCustomers[count].firstName << endl;
                cout << arrCustomers[count].lastName << endl;
                cout << arrCustomers[count].price << endl;
                cout << arrCustomers[count].carType << endl;
                cout << "------------------------" << endl;
                count++;
                */
        }
        fin.close();


        //displayCarTypeCounts(carCount);
        calcCarStats(arrCustomers, count, carCount);
        displayCarTypeCounts(carCount);


        _getch();
        return 0;
}

//<------Contents of Input.dat------------------>

Joe     Smith   5999.99 0
Mary    Doe     23999.99        1
Joe     Green   1999.99 1
Jim     Smith   4999.99 2
Jane    Green   3999.99 0
Mark    Doe     9999.99 1
John    Peters  7999.99 2
Jim     Green   8999.99 3
Mindy   Doe     3999.99 2
Janet   Green   6999.99 1
Mork    Doe     2999.99 3
Jane    Smith   3999.99 3
John    Roberts 15999.99        1
Mandy   Doe     12999.99        0
Janet   Smith   6999.99 0
Macy    Doe     14999.99        1
```

Comment: `index <= Toyota` better do this by inserting a sentinel in your enumeration, like `enum CarType { /*...*/, Toyota, CarType_END };` and then `index < CarType_END`. This decouples the iteration from the contents of the enumeration (a bit).

Comment: `while (!fin.eof())` wrong check. EOF is reached only after attempting to read beyond the end of the file. Also, this assumes the entries are always complete (and not, say, the type missing). Better check *after* reading via `>>`

Comment: Those arrays, like `carCount`, are not initialized. Reading from them (e.g. via `++`, which need to read and then stores the increment) invokes Undefined Behaviour. Better initialize your arrays, e.g. `int carCount[100] = {0};`

Comment: Also: Fixed size arrays require checks not to read/write out of bounds (imagine your file had 101 entries). Either implement those checks or (better idea) use automatically increasing "arrays" like `std::vector` (and `vector::push_back`).

Comment: `_tmain`, `_TCHAR`, `_getch` (and `conio.h`) are platform-dependent bad habits, and should be avoided. Better use `int main()` (or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`) and `std::cin.ignore()` instead of `_getch()` (though it's still a bad habit to let the console window stay open by using any of those tricks, better set up your IDE if possible to do that for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your arrays to zero before you start incrementing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

enum CarType
{
  Ford,
  Chevy,
  Honda,
  Toyota
};

struct CarCustomer
{
  string firstName;
  string lastName;
  double price;
  CarType carType;
};

void calcCarStats(CarCustomer arrCustomers[], int count, int carCount[])
{
  for(int index = 0; index < count; index++)
  {
    carCount[arrCustomers[index].carType]++;
  }
}

void displayCarTypeCounts(int carCount[])
{
  for(int index = Ford; index <= Toyota; index++)
  {
    cout //<< translateCarTypeToText((CarType)index) << " "
        << carCount[index] << endl;
  }
}

int main(int, char* [])
{
  int count = 0;
  CarCustomer arrCustomers[100]; //Array of structs for the Struct CarCustomer
  int carCount[100] = {0};
  double carPriceSum[100] = {0};
  double carPriceAvg[100] = {0};

  ifstream fin("input.dat");

  if(!fin)
  {
    cout << "Error opening file, check the file name" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  while (true)
  {
    // Joe     Smith   5999.99 0
    int carTypeInt;
    CarCustomer carCustomer;
    fin >> carCustomer.firstName
      >> carCustomer.lastName
      >> carCustomer.price
      >> carTypeInt;
    carCustomer.carType = (CarType)carTypeInt;  // carType entry is an enum
    if (!fin) { break; }
    arrCustomers[count++] = carCustomer;
  }
  fin.close();


  calcCarStats(arrCustomers, count, carCount);
  displayCarTypeCounts(carCount);

  return 0;
}
```