# C++ Find the sum of type x's price in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, enums

I'm stuck at the point of this program where I'm to calculate the sum of the price of all the CarType's.
For ex. The sum of the price for Ford's is **__**. The data is pulled from a file called input.dat.
I cannot for the life of me figure out how to group all Element's of a certain Car type and add up the sum then store the sum into the array carPriceSum. I understand how to find the sum of consecutive elements in an array. Any tips or examples would be much appreciated!

```
    // carstats.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h> // I understand this is not best practice
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

enum CarType
{
    Ford,
    Chevy,
    Honda,
    Toyota
};

struct CarCustomer
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    double price;
    CarType carType;
};

void calcCarStats(CarCustomer arrCustomers[], int count, int carCount[], double carPriceSum[])
{
    for(int index = 0; index < count; index++)
    {
        carCount[arrCustomers[index].carType]++;
        carPriceSum[index] = arrCustomers[index].price;
        // This is where I'm stuck
    }
} 

void displayCarTypeCounts(int carCount[], double carPriceSum[])
{
    for(int index = Ford; index <= Toyota; index++)
    {
        cout << carCount[index] << " " << carPriceSum[index] << endl;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int count = 0;
    CarCustomer arrCustomers[100]; //Array of structs for the Struct CarCustomer
    CarCustomer carCustomer;
    int carCount[100] = {0};
    double carPriceSum[100] = {0.0};
    double carPriceAvg[100] = {0.0};
    ifstream fin;
    CarType carType; //CarType enum

    fin.open("input.dat");

    if(!fin)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file, check the file name" << endl;
        _getch();
        return -1;
    }

    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        int carTypeInt;

        fin >> arrCustomers[count].firstName;
        fin >> arrCustomers[count].lastName;
        fin >> arrCustomers[count].price;
        fin >> carTypeInt; 
        arrCustomers[count].carType = (CarType)carTypeInt;
        count++;
    }
    fin.close();

    calcCarStats(arrCustomers, count, carCount, carPriceSum);
    displayCarTypeCounts(carCount, carPriceSum);


    _getch();
    return 0;
}


    //input.dat
Joe Smith   5999.99 0
Mary    Doe 23999.99 1
Joe Green   1999.99 1
Jim Smith   4999.99 2
Jane    Green   3999.99 0
Mark    Doe 9999.99 1
John    Peters  7999.99 2
Jim Green   8999.99 3
Mindy   Doe 3999.99 2
Janet   Green   6999.99 1
Mork    Doe 2999.99 3
Jane    Smith   3999.99 3
John    Roberts 15999.99    1
Mandy   Doe 12999.99    0
Janet   Smith   6999.99 0
Macy    Doe 14999.99    1
```

Comment: Have you heard of using a debugger? Also checking for errors?

Comment: Note: this - `while (!fin.eof())` is wrong, and *none* of the things you *should* be checking (each extraction) are being validated.

Comment: You'll want to keep a separate sum for each car type.

Comment: ... such as a `std::map<>` of car-type to accumulated total, updated as you read in your data.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Not only that, but that file reading bug was corrected here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777093/outputting-an-enum-of-a-struct-returns-negative-number/18777980#18777980

Comment: @AdamBurry Lovely. heh. see you back here tomorrow =P

Comment: @WhozCraig I volunteered that as a side note to my answer, actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to *add* to the "running" sum in `carPriceSum[n]`:

Change `calcCarStats` from

```
    carCount[arrCustomers[index].carType]++;
    carPriceSum[index] = arrCustomers[index].price;
    // This is where I'm stuck
```

To

```
    CarType type = arrCustomers[index].carType;

    carCount[type]++;
    carPriceSum[type] += arrCustomers[index].price;
```

---

Unrelated comments:

- Consider changing the read 'eof()' loop around:

  ```
  CarCustomer current;
  int carTypeInt;
  while (fin >> current.firstName >> current.lastName >> current.price >> carTypeInt)
  {
      current.carType = (CarType)carTypeInt;
      arrCustomers[count] = current;
      count++;
  }
  ```
- Consider printing the actual cartype in the `display` function:

  ```
  ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, CarType ct)
  {
      switch(ct)
      {
          case Ford:    return os << "Ford";
          case Chevy:   return os << "Chevy";
          case Honda:   return os << "Honda";
          case Toyota:  return os << "Toyota";
      }
      return os << "Unknown";
  }

  void displayCarTypeCounts(int carCount[], double carPriceSum[])
  {
      for(int index = Ford; index <= Toyota; index++)
      {
          cout << (CarType)index << " " << carCount[index] << " " << carPriceSum[index] << endl;
      }
  }
  ```
- Consider using standard library containers (map, vector): see a demo **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1258f783b931607d)**

  ```
  // carstats.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
  //
  #include <iostream>
  #include <iomanip>
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>
  #include <map>
  #include <fstream>
  using namespace std;

  enum CarType
  {
      Ford,
      Chevy,
      Honda,
      Toyota
  };

  struct Stats
  {
      unsigned units_sold;
      double total_turnover;
      Stats() : units_sold(0), total_turnover(0.0) {}
  };

  typedef map<CarType, Stats> Statistics;

  ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, CarType ct) {
      switch(ct) {
          case Ford:    return os << "Ford";
          case Chevy:   return os << "Chevy";
          case Honda:   return os << "Honda";
          case Toyota:  return os << "Toyota";
      }
      return os << "Unknown";
  }

  struct CarCustomer
  {
      string firstName;
      string lastName;
      double price;
      CarType carType;
  };

  Statistics calcCarStats(vector<CarCustomer> const& arrCustomers)
  {
      Statistics stats;
      for (auto& customer : arrCustomers)
      {
          auto& entry = stats[customer.carType];

          entry.units_sold     += 1;
          entry.total_turnover += customer.price;
      }

      return stats;
  } 

  void displayCarTypeCounts(Statistics const& stats)
  {
      for (auto& entry: stats)
          cout << (CarType)entry.first << " " << entry.second.units_sold << " " << entry.second.total_turnover << endl;
  }

  int main()
  {
      vector<CarCustomer> arrCustomers;
      ifstream fin("input.dat");

      if(!fin)
      {
          cout << "Error opening file, check the file name" << endl;
          return -1;
      }

      CarCustomer current;
      int carTypeInt;
      while (fin >> current.firstName >> current.lastName >> current.price >> carTypeInt)
      {
          current.carType = (CarType)carTypeInt;
          arrCustomers.push_back(current);
      }
      fin.close();

      auto stats = calcCarStats(arrCustomers);
      displayCarTypeCounts(stats);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do (but not most efficient) is to loop through arrCustomers looking for a particular car type and accumulate your sum. If you put that code in a function, then you can call it for each car type.